# Laravel 4 Eloquent paginate related model

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, relational-database, eloquent

I'm working on Laravel project that has two models: `Offer` belongsTo `Category`.

It's easy to paginate the results when I'm retrieving all records:

```
$offers = Offer::paginate(10);
```

But when I'm trying to just retrieve `Offers` that has specific `Category`, It just do not work:

```
$category = Category::whereId($category_id)->with('offers')->first()->paginate(10);
```

and I get this error:

```
 Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::$offers
```

### UPDATE:

I've solved it by replacing the second code with this:

```
$category = Category::find($category_id);
$offers = $category->offers()->paginate(10);
```

Comment: You can answer your own question and also except it so answer it and except it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace the second code with this:

```
$category = Category::find($category_id);
$offers = $category->offers()->paginate(10);
```

Comment: For the record, meanwhile this is ok: `$offers = $category->offers;`, this is not: `$offers = $category->offers->paginate(10);`. **Why?**